# Which version of Firebase should I use for Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

I am working on Angular 5 version and need to use firebase and firestore and its throwing an error
`ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` at new AngularFirestore
Which version of firebase should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebase version 4.6.1

npm install firebase@4.6.1

You can refer http://www.dotnetmob.com/angular-5-tutorial/angular-5-crud-operations-with-firebase/

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Angular are you using?

You can user Firebase [version 4.4.0.](https://libraries.io/npm/firebase/4.4.0)

This is compatible with Angular 5. 

To install this version you can use the following NPM command -

```
npm install firebase@4.4.0
```